# Return HtmlDocument of redirected page (HtmlAgilityPack)

Tags: c#, request, html-agility-pack, htmldoc

I'm sending POST request to my own site and after that its redirect to the other page. How to get HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument of redirected page? Thanks so much guys.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Bad English is not the reason you will get no help. We can't help you unless you share the code you have and tell us where the problem is (what error are you getting)?

Comment: Thanks Dude! I solved the problem :)

Comment: Care to share how you solved the problem?